# Allow special characters in tag button attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have a button which need to have some attributes/elements like id, explanation, reason, etc.
This button is added to a dynamic table with the help of ajax and the dynatable plugin, to add the buttons I use the writters option and add it this way:

```
actions: function (record)
    var btn = "<button class='btn btn-sm action-btn-edit'
             id='" + record.id + "' explanation='" + record.explanation + "'                                       record.explanation + "'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></button>";
             return "<div class='btn-group'>" + btnEdit + "</div>";
```

this button will fetch data from a table to it's respective attributes in the button, id, explanation, reason.
The problem is the explanation might be too long and also contain special characters, and when I deploy this the text in that attribute ends up showing inside the actual button.

Is there any solution to allow special characters in the attributes, as I think that is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution would be to use the button id to reference a JSON structure that holds the data, In my example I just cache the record data in my button render function.

```
 var _CACHE={}; // we store our data here;

 function editBtn(record){
   _CACHE[record.id] = record; // make a reference to our data in a global
   var btn = "<button class='btn btn-sm action-btn-edit' id='" + record.id + "'>"
   return btn;
 }

 function btnClick(btn){
    // get the record this button represents using its id   
    var data =  _CACHE[btn.id];

    // so something with your data: data.explanation, etc.
 }
```

Comment: Thank you it seems an excellent idea, after you recommended this I actually came up with an idea, which was use JSON.stringify(record.explanation), it actually does something and the amount of text that shows in the button is much less, but there's still text written inside the button...

Comment: I think from a design point of view, you are far better making your buttons reference JSON objects in your application. It is quite a common practice to build cache objects around buttons and elements, your concept is also often used for smaller amounts of data in which case you should use data-explanation="{somedata]". Can you accept my answer?